# How can I get the last price from Coinmarketcap API

Tags: php, arrays, api

I'm trying to get the last price in USD from this coin:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2424/');
echo $json;

?>
```

I tried two different options on the JSON object like `[0]['price]`
Nothing works.

Comment: First you need to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

The response from coinmarketcap is in JSON, so you need to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it.

The second paramter of json_decode lets you decide if its a object or array. For an array, mark this as true

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2424/');
$objResponse = json_decode($json, true);

echo $objResponse['data']['quotes']['USD']['price'];
```